# Can not read Japanese content from Wiki

Tags: java, parsing, encoding, mediawiki

I am trying to use below code to read the Japanese content from Wiki

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
client = Client.create(clientConfig);
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=AKB48&rvprop=content&prop=revisions");
String s  = webResource.get(String.class);          
System.out.println(s);
```

And the result is like

```
{"query":{"pages":{"2276803":{"pageid":2276803,"ns":0,"title":"AKB48","revisions":[{"contentformat":"text/x-wiki","contentmodel":"wikitext","*":"{{Otheruseslist|\u65e5\u672c\u306e\u5973\u6027\u30a2\u30a4\u30c9\u30eb\u30b0\u30eb\u30fc\u30d7....
```

It shows \uxxx rather than real Japanese words. I know it must be encoding issue. But I still can not make it works.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like entirely reasonable JSON to me. Like Java, JSON uses `\u` escape sequences to represent characters. I don't think this is an encoding issue at all.

I suggest you find a JSON parser with an API you like, plug the string into that, and then you'll be able to fetch the "unescaped" values.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It works if I transfer the result to Object with `Jackson`! Before I just wanted to read the String result first...